# Minimum NUnit binaries for an OSS project

Tags: unit-testing, nunit

Open Source projects that ship with unit tests based on NUnit also usually ship the NUnit runners and accompanying binaries. For NUnit 2.4.8, distributing its `bin` directory verbatim with the actual project amounts to 46 files and a blank `addins` directory. What would be the minimum set of files needed if all one wanted was to distribute the GUI and console runners along with the base `nunit.framework.dll` required for authoring tests (and without the mocking infrastructure)?

For reference, the NUnit 2.4.8 `bin` directory looks like this:

- addins/
- clr.bat
- failure.jpg
- fit.dll
- ignored.jpg
- loadtest-assembly.dll
- mock-assembly.dll
- nonamespace-assembly.dll
- notestfixtures-assembly.dll
- nunit.core.dll
- nunit.core.extensions.dll
- nunit.core.interfaces.dll
- nunit.core.tests.dll
- nunit.exe
- nunit.exe.config
- nunit.extensions.tests.dll
- nunit.fixtures.dll
- nunit.fixtures.tests.dll
- nunit.framework.dll
- nunit.framework.extensions.dll
- nunit.framework.tests.dll
- nunit.framework.xml
- nunit.mocks.dll
- nunit.mocks.tests.dll
- nunit.uikit.dll
- nunit.uikit.tests.dll
- nunit.util.dll
- nunit.util.tests.dll
- nunit-console.exe
- nunit-console.exe.config
- nunit-console.tests.dll
- nunit-console-runner.dll
- nunit-console-x86.exe
- nunit-console-x86.exe.config
- NUnitFitTests.html
- nunit-gui.tests.dll
- nunit-gui-runner.dll
- NUnitTests.config
- NUnitTests.nunit
- nunit-x86.exe
- nunit-x86.exe.config
- runFile.exe
- runFile.exe.config
- success.jpg
- test-assembly.dll
- test-utilities.dll
- timing-tests.dll

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I can successfully run tests with only the following 6 NUnit files present:

- nunit.core.dll
- nunit.core.interfaces.dll
- nunit.framework.dll
- nunit.util.dll
- nunit.console-runner.dll
- nunit-console.exe

Comment: And for the GUI runner, I suppose one would only need to add nunit-gui-runner.dll, nunit.exe and nunit.exe.config to your list?

Comment: Well, maybe - to calirify my statement a bit: If running tests is part of your build process and/or you need to run tests on a CI server, then the 6 files I mention are the only ones needed.

I don't know (or care :)) about the GUI runner - R# has a GUI runner that made me leave the NUnit GUI runner and never look back :)

Answer (score 2):

After some research, the following files don't appear to be unnecessary because they represent test assemblies for NUnit itself and for FIT:

- addins/
- clr.bat
- failure.jpg
- <del>fit.dll</del>
- ignored.jpg
- loadtest-assembly.dll
- mock-assembly.dll
- nonamespace-assembly.dll
- notestfixtures-assembly.dll
- nunit.core.dll
- nunit.core.extensions.dll
- nunit.core.interfaces.dll
- <del>nunit.core.tests.dll</del>
- nunit.exe
- nunit.exe.config
- <del>nunit.extensions.tests.dll</del>
- nunit.fixtures.dll
- <del>nunit.fixtures.tests.dll</del>
- nunit.framework.dll
- nunit.framework.extensions.dll
- <del>nunit.framework.tests.dll</del>
- nunit.framework.xml
- nunit.mocks.dll
- <del>nunit.mocks.tests.dll</del>
- nunit.uikit.dll
- <del>nunit.uikit.tests.dll</del>
- nunit.util.dll
- <del>nunit.util.tests.dll</del>
- nunit-console.exe
- nunit-console.exe.config
- <del>nunit-console.tests.dll</del>
- nunit-console-runner.dll
- nunit-console-x86.exe
- nunit-console-x86.exe.config
- <del>NUnitFitTests.html</del>
- <del>nunit-gui.tests.dll</del>
- nunit-gui-runner.dll
- <del>NUnitTests.config</del>
- <del>NUnitTests.nunit</del>
- nunit-x86.exe
- nunit-x86.exe.config
- <del>runFile.exe</del>
- <del>runFile.exe.config</del>
- success.jpg
- test-assembly.dll
- test-utilities.dll
- timing-tests.dll

Answer (score 1):

For 2.6, in addition to Mooki's list, I had to add:

- nunit-agent.exe