# What are the minimum required dependencies for the NUnit console?

Tags: nunit, nunit-console

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Minimum NUnit binaries for an OSS project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/342128/minimum-nunit-binaries-for-an-oss-project)

I would like to use [this custom NUnit build activity](http://tfsbuildextensions.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=How%20to%20integrate%20the%20nUnit%20build%20activity&referringTitle=Documentation) on the TFS 2010 build server. It runs NUnit test the same way as MSTest on the build server (with full reporting). It requires the the *nunit-console.exe* to be run on the build server, so I need to put it there.

What are the minimum required files that *nunit-console.exe* (current version 2.6) depends on that I need to put on the sever too? It seem than NUnit itself comes with a lot of files that might not all be required if I just want to run the console.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I never used the NUnit installer so I wasn't aware of its features but if you uncheck everything in the NUnit installer, it seems that the bare minimum gets installed, which in version 2.6 evaluates to the following files and folders. I suppose in my case I could even omit all the **agent* stuff and [maybe even the *NUnit.Mocks.dll*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2884040/where-is-the-nunit-mocks-documentation#5180994):

```
Logo.ico
license.txt
\bin
\bin\nunit-agent.exe.config
\bin\nunit-agent-x86.exe.config
\bin\nunit-console.exe.config
\bin\nunit-console-x86.exe.config
\bin\nunit-agent.exe
\bin\nunit-agent-x86.exe
\bin\nunit-console.exe
\bin\nunit-console-x86.exe
\bin\framework
\bin\framework\nunit.framework.dll
\bin\framework\nunit.mocks.dll
\bin\framework\nunit.framework.xml
\bin\lib
\bin\lib\nunit.core.dll
\bin\lib\nunit.core.interfaces.dll
\bin\lib\nunit.util.dll
\bin\lib\nunit-console-runner.dll
```